# Android Studio: Redirecting to the phone's Google Maps App with a start and end address pre-filled

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, android-intent, direction

I would like to redirect the user to the Google Maps apps on the phone through intents I assume to get the direction/route. However, I would like the user to enter in the address for both starting and destination. Using this information, I hope to open the Maps with the starting and ending point inputted. (The starting and ending address will be in string format, as opposed to Lat/long).

I did research but I am still confused on how to proceed.

Appreciate any help regarding this inquiry.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the official documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/android-intents). You just need to pass the geo points via an Intent. For example, to display a map of San Francisco, you can use the following code:

```
Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("geo:37.7749,-122.4194");
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
if (mapIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
    startActivity(mapIntent);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Prokash. Is it possible to specify the starting and ending address? Is there a way to pass in two strings holding the starting and ending address for me to get directions?

Answer (score 2):

This is how you pass an address that Google Maps. You dont have to necessarily pass the lat and long.

```
Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain+View, California");
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
startActivity(mapIntent);
```

You can get more info [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/android-intents#location_search).

Comment: Thanks Arun! I was wondering how we get the directions by specifying BOTH the starting and ending address? I did look at the resource you linked in, however it did not explain how to get directions with both starting and ending address. Not sure if I am missing something.

Comment: Should be accepted answer, because that link gives all the info needed to do all things, like enter a query term, driving directions etc.